# Is it possible to use conditions in nginx config in order to have same config file for test and production?

Tags: nginx

I want to use the same config nginx site config file for test and change only the servername and port.

How can I achieve that or something close to it?

I want something like: if hostname==xxx listen on 80 else listen on 81.

Answer (score 2):

You could put all the shared parts in a separate file (say, `common.conf`) and include that in two minimalistic `server` blocks, like this:

```
http {
    [...]
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name production.local;

        root /some/path/production;
        include common.conf;
    }

    server {
        listen 81;
        server_name testing.local;

        root /some/path/testing;
        include common.conf;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Actually, you don't even need the `listen` directives. They default to `listen 80` when running as root, and to `listen 8000` otherwise. As long as you have a DNS entry, or hosts file entry, you'd be good.

Comment: you are right in saying that they default to port 80. Even if you write that it will give you an error saying 8080 being used by another port. So essentially url will be www.example.com:80 but you don't need to write 80 as it is there by default. but for serving www.example2.com:8084 you will need to mention the port number to get the address. How to make it work without explicitly adding the port address??

Comment: It will not complain about port 8080 being in use if you don't have `listen 8080;` anywhere in your configuration. [It might complain about port 8000 if you're not running nginx as root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen). In any case, if you want to use port 8084, you will have to have `listen 8084;` (or similar) somewhere in your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `bash/sh`. Unix way.

Comment: Could you elaborate? This is a very cryptic answer.

Comment: You should use scripting for deployment your site, and run command like `make production` or `make testing` that will automatically generate nginx config.

Comment: The question did not include any reference to deployment, so I'm assuming it revolves around running a production version and a test version side-by-side using nginx.